# Substring and return list of comma separated characters

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008

`Domain\X_User|X_User,Domain\Y_User|Y_User,`

I'm using a SSRS report and I'm receiving the above value, I want to write visual basic function in the report ( Custom code) to split the above string and return the following value:

`X_User,Y_User`

I tried to write this code inside a custom code of the report body:

```
Public Function SubString_Owner(X As String) As String


    Dim OwnerArray() As String = Split(X, ",")

    Dim Names As String

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    While i <= OwnerArray.Length - 1

         Dim NamesArr As String() = Split(OwnerArray(0), "|")

         Names = NamesArr(1) + ","

             i += 1

    End While

    Return Names
End Function
```

The problem is when trying to split `OwnerArray(i)`, it gives an error but when using a fixed value, like `zero`, it builds fine. Can anyone figure out why this is?

Comment: Any reason you are using the `Split` function from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace instead of the `Split` method built into the `String` class?

Comment: Are you using this code inside of VB .Net or inside of SSRS?

Comment: Inside SSRS report body

Comment: Wasn't clear on that.  Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic solution that will work with any number of items:

```
Dim sourceString As String = "Domain\X_User|X_User,Domain\Y_User|Y_User,"
Dim domainsAndUsers As IEnumerable(Of String) = sourceString.Split(","c).Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
Dim usersWithoutDomains As IEnumerable(Of String) = domainsAndUsers.Select(Function(s) s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf("\") + 1))
Dim users As IEnumerable(Of String) = usersWithoutDomains.Select(Function(s) s.Remove(s.IndexOf("|")))   
Dim result As String = users.Aggregate(Function(s, d) s & "," & d)
```

Or if you want it as a single-line function, here:

```
  Function Foo(sourceString As String) As String
    Return sourceString.Split(","c).Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).Select(Function(s) s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf("\") + 1)).Select(Function(s) s.Remove(s.IndexOf("|"))).Aggregate(Function(s, d) s & "," & d)
  End Function
```

EDIT:

You may have to add `Imports System.Linq` to the top.  Not sure if SSRS can use LINQ or not.  If not, then here is a similar solution without LINQ:

```
Dim sourceString As String = "Domain\X_User|X_User,Domain\Y_User|Y_User,"
Dim domainsAndUsers As IEnumerable(Of String) = sourceString.Split(","c)
Dim usersWithoutDomains As String = String.Empty
For Each domainUser As String In domainsAndUsers
    usersWithoutDomains &= domainUser.Remove(0, domainUser.IndexOf("\") + 1) & ","
Next
```

Comment: Your code gives an error that When is not a collection of system.array

Comment: There is no "when".  It should be `Where`.

Comment: Sorry , I meant where not when

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim strTest As String = "Domain\X_User|X_User,Domain\Y_User|Y_User"

    MsgBox(strTest.Split("|")(0).Split("\")(1) & " " & strTest.Split("|")(1).Split("\")(1))
```

Comment: A few issues here:
1.  This won't compile with `Option Strict On`
2.  It doesn't put a comma between the values.
3.  Since it uses hard-coded array indexes, it only works if there are exactly 2 items coming from the report.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way that will work with variable data as long as the pattern you've shown is strongly followed:

```
Imports System.Linq

    Dim strtest As String = "Domain\X_User|X_User,Domain\Y_User|Y_User,"
    'This splits the string according to "|" and ",".  Now any string without _
    a "\" is the user and Join adds them together with `,` as a delimiter
    Dim result As String = Join((From s In strtest.Split("|,".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                Where Not s.Contains("\")
                                Select s).ToArray, ",")
```

Just in case LINQ is unavailable to you here's a different way to the same results without LINQ:

```
    Dim result As String = ""
    For Each s As String In strtest.Split("|,".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If Not s.Contains("\") Then
            result += s & ","
        End If
    Next
    result = result.TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray)
```

Comment: I tried this solution inside a function of the report body but it gives an error that some function need namespace

Comment: See if `Imports System.Linq` helps.  I added an alternative method in case it doesn't